# Combination pairing with in respect to time/cycle

Tags: java, sorting

So I am doing a project where lets say there are 4 teams (Sources) of TV's (LG, Panasonic, etc) and 4 teams (Sink) of gaming consoles (XBox, PS3, Wii etc). My goal is to try and schedule the teams together so total of 4*4 = 16 pairs something like

Time        Sources     paired with   Sinks
9:00 AM 
            Source 1                  Sink 1
            Source 2                  Sink 2
            Source 3                  Sink 3
            Source 4                  Sink 4

9:30 AM     Source 1                  Sink 4
            Source 2                  Sink 1
            Source 3                  Sink 2
            Source 4                  Sink 3

10:00 AM    Source 1                  Sink 3
            Source 2                  Sink 4
            Source 3                  Sink 1
            Source 4                  Sink 2

10:30 AM    Source 1                  Sink 2
            Source 2                  Sink 3
            Source 3                  Sink 4
            Source 4                  Sink 1

Question is, what is the best way to pair them up, including that all sources are stored in one ArrayList and all Sinks are stored in the other ArrayList

Comment: Show some code of what you tried or what you thought of so far. You can't expect an answer with the full code solving your problem on stackoverflow. Show some code and the people will gladly give you a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty easy just to iterate over both collections...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] sourcesArray = new String[]{"LG", "Panasonic"};
    String[] sinksArray = new String[]{"Xbox", "PS3"};
    // you have your data as List
    List<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sourcesArray));
    List<String> sinks = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sinksArray));

    for (String source : sources)
    {
        for (String sink : sinks)
        {
            System.out.println(source + ":" + sink);
        }
    }
}
```

You could then group the result, add timestamps, put it in another collection or whatever...